# Select command denied for user

Tags: sql

I have read numerous other threads on this issue, but my problem is that I don't have higher access to phpmyadmin than access to tables so I cannot edit my privileges.

My sql is :

`SELECT * FROM sh_shoe INNER JOIN sh_brand ON brandID.sh_shoe, brandID.sh_brand WHERE 1`

the tables are

```
sh_shoe, sh_brand
```

and my error message is :

> SELECT command denied to user 'unn_w14007417'@'localhost' for table 'sh_brand'

now I can change the table to remove the join and the SELECT statement still works just without the other table that's required. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and I really just don't understand what I'm missing.

edit: I should've stated, I do have access to that table. Which is why I'm confused that it isnt working.

Comment: Whoever manages the Database, ask them to setup the permission for user unn_w14007417 on the sh_brand table

Comment: You have access to the first table [sh_shoe] but not the right to select [sh_brand]. It can be done in numerous way by your DBA in charge (those can be views and not tables for example, they can lie in different filegorups, the rules can be tailored at table level, etc). Ask your DBA to allow you to select the table

Answer (score 1):

Your user *unn_w14007417* has no access rights for a select statement on the *sh_brand* table.

Comment: This should be a comment, if anything. It's just an interpretation of the error message. OP knows that already.

Comment: Sorry, not enought reputation for comments :(

Comment: But the strange thing is if i remove the join and just use sh_brand it works fine.

Comment: The user unn_w14007417  has access rights for sh_shoe and not for sh_brand. Does a "SELECT * FROM sh_brand" work?

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't work. I'm going to have to email my lecturer. thanks!